# Solution verification: limit of a sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I started by transforming to exponential form:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2}}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(2^n+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}}
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln{(2^n+n^2)}}}$$
Then factored the biggest term, simplified and got the limit of exponent:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\ln{(2^n+n^2)}}=
lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\ln{\left(2^n\left(1+\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)\right)}}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\ln{2^n}+\ln{1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\ln{2}}=\ln2
$$
Leading to:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2}}=e^{\ln2}$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Looks fine, though this solution looks a bit too complicated for this limit. Much easier to use the inequalities $2^n\leq 2^n+n^2\leq 2\cdot 2^n$, and the squeeze theorem. Also, in the final answer note that $e^{\ln 2}=2$.

Comment: It is correct but 
$\frac 1 n\ln({1+\frac {n^{2}}{2^{n}}})\to 1$ requires a proof.

Comment: as geetha said that passage needs proof

Answer (score 0):

I’d state that the expression is 2, multiplied by the n-th root of $1 + n^2 / 2^n$. And $1 + n^2 / 2^n$ converges to 1 even without taking a root.